# VS Code doesn't switch between Anaconda environments correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, pythoninterpreter

I have:

- two conda environments, `myenv1` and `myenv2`;
- two folders containing `.py` files: `folder1` and `folder2`.

Let's say I've been working on `folder1` in VS Code using `myenv1`, and then I do the following:

- I close `folder1` (using `File -> Close Folder`)
- I open `folder2` (using `File -> Open Folder...`).
- I switch to `env2` using the `Python: Select Interpreter` command.

What happens?

- The blue information bar at the bottom of the VS Code window says "Python 3.8.2 64-bit ('env2': conda)" -- this suggests to me I'm now working in `env2`.
- But I don't think the VS Code has correctly switched to `env2`. Why? Because if I attempt to import a package that exists in `env2` but not `env1` I get an error. If I import a package that exists in `env1` but not `env2` the import is successful.

But if I close VS Code and open it again (without doing anything else), the switch to `env2` has been successful (by performing the same import test).

Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong? I've tried to find the issue on github without success.

Many thanks for your help.

Frank.

PS: I guess I could manually set `sys.executable` but I'd like to use the VS Code functionality if possible.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting when trying to import? Is this in the editor or is it when you execute code? And due to how conda wants to own the environment it's easiest to launch VS Code from the activated environment you want to work with.

Comment: @BrettCannon It's a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I will try figure out how to launch VS Code as you suggest and see if this helps.